# Java throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if using a regular if loop, but not if using an enhanced for loop. Why?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Source code:

```
public class Main {
    String line;
    static List<String> currentProcesses = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.contains("System Idle Process")) {
                    System.out.println(line);

                    String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");               
                    if (!splitLine[0].contains("=") && !splitLine[0].equals("Image")) {
                        //this is the erroenous part of code
                        String[] refinedSplitLine = eliminateSpacebarCharacters(splitLine);

                        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
                            System.out.println(refinedSplitLine[i]);
                        }
                        /*
                        for(String s:refinedSplitLine) {
                            System.out.println(s);
                        }
                        */

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Eliminates spacebar characters from a file and returns a String array
     * @param line
     * @return
     */
    private static String[] eliminateSpacebarCharacters(String[] line) {    
        List<String> refinedList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String s : line) {
            if (!s.equals("")) {
                refinedList.add(s);
            }
        }

        String[] refinedStringArray = new String[refinedList.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < refinedStringArray.length; i++) {
            refinedStringArray[i] = refinedList.get(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Displaying refinedStringArray...");
        ArrayUtils.displayArray(refinedStringArray);

        return refinedStringArray;
    }
}
```

My program does the following:

- Get an access and read (using a BufferedReader) all currently open system processes. Each system process is represented by a line, for example (due to formatting there is obnoxiously lot of whitespace characters; first line element refers to the so called Image Name, the second to PID, the third to Session Name, the fourth to session number and the fifth to memory usage of that process):

`System                           4 Services                   0      2.608 K`

- Then, each line is split into a String array based on spacebar characters (`String[] splitLine`).
- Then, each such array is eliminated of whitespace characters using the method `String[] eliminateSpacebarCharacters(String[] line)`. This, whitespace-character-free String array is called `refinedSplitLine`.
- **An error occurs when trying to access elements of refinedSplitLine**

I've tried displaying the refined string array (eliminated of whitespace characters) inside `eliminateSpacebarCharacters` by the following lines of code

```
System.out.println("Displaying refinedStringArray...");
ArrayUtils.displayArray(refinedStringArray);

//this is displayArray method in ArrayUtils class
public static void displayArray(String[] array) {
    int i = 0;
    for (String s:array) {
        System.out.print("[" + i + "]: " + s + " ");
        i++;
    }
}
```

And this displays the wanted result: `[0]: WmiPrvSE.exe [1]: 23156 [2]: Services [3]: 0 [4]: 8.680 [5]: K`, which means that the array which is returned by the method IS populated with elements.

Now, this code section is going to demonstrate the occurrence of such an error. If trying to access whatever element of refinedSplitLine by it's index inside the `if (!splitLine[0].contains("=") && !splitLine[0].equals("Image"))` clause, an exception gets thrown. Why?

```
if (!splitLine[0].contains("=") && !splitLine[0].equals("Image")) {
        String[] refinedSplitLine = eliminateSpacebarCharacters(splitLine);
        System.out.println(refinedSplitLine[0]);
}
```

This is the thrown exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Main.main(Main.java:27) //this line refers to System.out.println above
```

The same error gets thrown if trying to use a regular for loop to access elements of `refinedSplitLine`. **However, if trying to use an enhanced for loop, no error gets thrown. Why?**

```
if (!splitLine[0].contains("=") && !splitLine[0].equals("Image")) {
                    String[] refinedSplitLine = eliminateSpacebarCharacters(splitLine);
                    //ArrayUtils.displayArray(refinedSplitLine);

                    for(String s:refinedSplitLine) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }

                    /*
                    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
                        System.out.println(refinedSplitLine[i]);
                    }*/
```

**The refinedSplitLine is populated with elements, however if trying to access them, an error gets thrown, like if there were no elements in the array.**

Thank you for the time taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using for loop in wrong way. You cannot be sure that **refinedSplitLine** contains an element. Just replace following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    System.out.println(refinedSplitLine[i]);
}
```

With this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<refinedSplitLine.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(refinedSplitLine[i]);
}
```

For each works fine because it iterate through all elements of array, if it's empty it just doesn't print anything. But normal loop in your case try to get element from array which index doesn't exists that's why you have an exception.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Realised it was a dumb mistake :C

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` indicates you're accessing a zero length array where all indexes are out of bounds.

The foreach loop will just skip it since it sees there's no elements. Your other loop seems to expect there to be 4 elements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, appreciate it.